# Как решить проблему с matchMedia на Андроид устройствах?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

От предыдущего программиста достался код

```
function setupForWidth(mql) {
    if(mql.matches) {
        menu.classList.remove('hidden');
        document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('mod-position-f')
    } else {
        menu.classList.add('hidden');
        bodyPosition(menu, 'hidden');
    }
}

var mql = window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 768px)");

if(menu) {
    mql.addListener(setupForWidth);
    setupForWidth(mql)
}
```

все это висит на DOMContentLoaded

И во всех браузерах кроме Android Browser корректно работает. Андроид браузер игнорирует условие и отрабатывает вариант else всегда... помогите разобраться...

Сайт Orby.ru
При открытии с андроид устройства через родной браузер меню перекрывает все.